# how to get the deleted item value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have removed an element from an array. Now, I need to display which item is deleted and the remaining items, but have been unsuccessful. Suppose, the array looks like:

```
let person = ['Cercei','Snow','Arya','Sansa']
```

I have removed 'Snow' and 'Cercei'. So, I need to display two things into two different new array.

```
delPerson = ['Cercei','Snow'] 
remArray = ['Arya','Sansa']
```

How can this be done with JavaScript? In my application, I have delete icon with each and every name so i can remove any name. I want to get the deleted name and remaining name into two different array. Please help me how to do that using javascript or lodash

let me tell you my application code:

```
let person = personData.map(n => n.name) 
let remPerson = person.filter(p => person.indexOf(p) !== -1)
```

Now, person and remPerson array is showing same value. While comparing the length it is creating the problem.

Comment: Share more of you javascript code to show how you are deleting the items.

Comment: i have used indexof method to do that.. but every time it is displaying two array with same value in console. delete is working properly. by using this logic i have to compare two array

Comment: Try using `splice` perhaps?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: i am asking the remaining item logic by using es6 or lodash. other things are working correct

Comment: @j3py can you give some working example. it will be helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const persons = ['Cercei', 'Snow', 'Arya', 'Sansa'];

const {
  deleted,
  kept
} = persons.reduce((acc, person) => {
  // Note: The deletion condition may vary
  if (person === 'Cercei' || person === 'Snow') {
    acc.deleted.push(person);
  } else {
    acc.kept.push(person);
  }

  return acc;
}, {
  deleted: [],
  kept: []
});

console.log(deleted);
console.log(kept);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice`, but this will modify your original array.  It is unclear to me if that will be ok in the OP's case.  Here's Mozilla's documentation on `splice`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```js
let person = ['Cercei','Snow','Arya','Sansa'];

let delPerson = person.splice(0, 2);

console.log(delPerson);
console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove items using splice and also keep track of two separate arrays:

```js
let personData  = [{name:'Cercei'},{name:'Snow'},{name:'Arya'},{name:'Sansa'}];
let person      = personData.map(n=>n.name);
let removeItems = ['Cercei','Snow'];
let delPerson   = [];

removeItems.forEach(item=>{
  delPerson.push( 
    ...person.splice( person.indexOf(item), 1 )
  )
});

console.log('delPerson: ', delPerson);
console.log('remaining: ', person);
```